# Getting AttributeError when using openAI python library

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, openai-api, gpt-4

I'm building a new AI chatbot utilizing the openai library and I have a gradio UI set up in one file (app.py) and a predict() function in another (trainedBot.py)
Every time I send a request through the gradio UI I get this error:

```
File "/home/user/app/trainedBot.py", line 48, in predict
    return response.choices.message.content
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'message'
```

I tried putting both the message and the openAI response in a variable and nothing happened. Still got the same error. The response looked like this:

```json
{
  "id": "chatcmpl-8CHKgpOewruWDC2Et1R6ZFtdPmSQR",
  "object": "chat.completion",
  "created": 1697937254,
  "model": "gpt-4-0613",
  "choices": [
    {
      "index": 0,
      "message": {
        "role": "assistant",
        "content": "HIIIIIII"
      },
      "finish_reason": "stop"
    }
  ],
  "usage": {
    "prompt_tokens": 308,
    "completion_tokens": 4,
    "total_tokens": 312
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
response = {
  "id": "chatcmpl-8CHKgpOewruWDC2Et1R6ZFtdPmSQR",
  "object": "chat.completion",
  "created": 1697937254,
  "model": "gpt-4-0613",
  "choices": [
    {
      "index": 0,
      "message": {
        "role": "assistant",
        "content": "HIIIIIII"
      },
      "finish_reason": "stop"
    }
  ],
  "usage": {
    "prompt_tokens": 308,
    "completion_tokens": 4,
    "total_tokens": 312
  }
}
```

Your choices is a `list` so access it you need to put `[0]`

```
print(response['choices'][0]['message']['content'])

'HIIIIIII'
```

Or could be:

```
response.get('choices')[0].get('message').get('content')
```